# Wordpress edit individual microsite's theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a Franchise site that I am working on. We setup at least 15 locations, and the microsite is serving well except for the fact of adding custom elements to the individual franchise locations.

How do I edit an individual microsite without having to mess with the "Network Admin" theme editor?

The Franchisee wants a block to be changed on the homepage: 'home-template.php'

Is there a way I can add the editor to the microsites?

Also, is there a way I can edit the CSS for an individual microsite?

Thank you,
Kyle

P.S. If anyone requires more information, please leave a comment, and I'll edit this question immediately.

Edit:

Here is how the block in question is being loaded from the template:

```
<div class="col span_4_of_12">
    <?php $posts = get_posts( "category_name=home_04" ); ?>
    <?php if( $posts ) : ?>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
      <div id="box-personal_svc_bg">
        <div class="sq-label_box_gr">
          <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
            <?php the_title();?>
          </a></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>      
 </div>
```

So, the franchisee wants to change the picture for that block (which is a background css attribute, and they also want to change the link - which I believe could be changed by just changing the category of the page/post to home_04, right?)

Even though one problem was partially resolved, is there still a way I can add an editor to each microsite?

Comment: if the microsites are page based then you can assign custom field to the pages which you can use as custom css for every microsite. else you have to tell what type of structure you are relying on to get the better answer.

Comment: Edited the question, and yes. The microsites are page/post based.

I am thinking about adding the custom field for the CSS, that's a great idea. Thank you.